# Jinja2 url_for blueprint function

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

Good evening, 
I'm developing a Flask-Python Web App but I'm having some trouble implementing the search route.
Here's my **html form**

```
 <!-- Buttons -->
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="/about"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> About</a></li>
          {% if not g.user.is_authenticated %}
          <li><a href="/signup"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
          <li><a href="/login"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
          {% endif %}
          <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">

          <!-- Search -->
          <li>
          <form class="form-inline" method="GET" action="{{ url_for('home.search') }}">
              <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="query" id="query">
              </div>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
          </form>
          </li>

          </form>
          {% if g.user.is_authenticated %}
          <li><a href="/logout"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span> Logout</a></li>
          {% endif %}
        </ul>
```

**And my search function:**

```
@home_blueprint.route("/search/")
@login_required
def search():

    results = Politic.query.whoosh_search(request.args.get('query')).all()
    #results = Politic.query.whoosh_search(query).all()
    for p in results:
        print p.publicName
    print results
    return render_template('search_results.html',
                           results=results)
```

When I make a search on my app, I get this URL:

> http://localhost:5000/home?query=Peter

When I want to get this:

> http://localhost:5000/search?query=Peter

I used the url_map function to see if everything is ok and it actually looks decent:

```
<Rule '/search/' (HEAD, OPTIONS, GET) -> home.search>,
```

I've struggling with this for a really long time and nothing seems to be wrong. Any possible help?

Regards

Comment: why do you have two `</form>` in HTML ? Do you have second `<form action="...">` ?

Comment: Sorry, edited. @furas

Comment: I still see two closing tag `</form>` and only one opening tag `<form>`. If you have second opening tag `<form>` then browser will you `action=` from external `<form>`

Comment: @furas Sorry, now it's good

Comment: @Perseverance can you show your `home_blueprint` definition? (where you call the `Blueprint()`)